# How do I take all of an object's properties and insert them into its own object array property?

Tags: javascript

For example I want something like:

```
{ 
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

turned into:

```
{
  d: { 
       a: 1,
       b: 2,
       c: 3
     }
}
```

I've tried assigning a new property to that object with the object itself but it shows up as circular so I figure it's a reference instead of the actual properties instead of the actual values. I want to try something like JSON.stringify the object and assign it to the property but I don't know how to turn that string into an object format that I can assign to the property.

Comment: Welcome. Please [edit] your question and show us the code you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let firstObj = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

let secondObj =  {};
secondObj.d = firstObj;
console.log(secondObj);
```

Basically you create a new object and assign the original object to its property `d`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 destructuting to make a shallow copy of the object and put it on a new prop:

```js
let obj = { 
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}
obj.d = {...obj}

console.log(obj)
```

If that's not an option you can `reduce()` over the objects keys to make a new object and assign it to `d`:

```js
let obj = { 
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}

obj.d = Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, k) => {
    newObj[k] = obj[k]
    return newObj
},{})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you want to make the deep or shallow copy of the object `d`. (Can the object `d` have a nested structure?)

The question about efficient ways to clone the object has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object).